# Why isn't the Fractional typeclass inherently orderable in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

Let's say I have the following code:

```
import Data.List
f :: (Fractional a) => [a] -> Int -> a
f xs n = sort xs !! n
```

This won't compile because `sort` is of type `Ord a => [a] -> [a]`. This seems odd to me, as I figured all `Num`-type values would be inherently orderable. To fix this issue I would need to add an additional type constraint (i.e. `(Fractional a, Ord a) => [a] -> Int -> a`). Looking at Haskell's documentation, this makes sense from a [syntactic / hierarchal perspective](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/classes.gif).

Still, what gives? Why are real values orderable, but not fractional values? I don't understand the rationale.

Comment: You could also have *algebraic* `Fractionals`. Like for instance `(Variable 'x' + Constant 1)`, etc. to represent `x + 1`. So in that case you can perform additions, multiplications, etc., but no comparison.

Comment: Note that one, with extensions, can define `type FractOrd a = (Fractional a, Ord a)` to define a more convenient name, if wished.

Comment: @chi Wasn't aware of that language feature. Cool!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Would it be possible to see an executable example that illustrates this, or some documentation?

Comment: @kylemart https://github.com/leftaroundabout/Symbolic-math-HaTeX/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Fractional` is not a type, but rather a type class for types supporting real division. Your question then becomes why `Fractional` doesn't have `Ord` as a superclass. As for that, [`Complex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Complex.html) is a good counterexample of a type supporting division but no sensible total ordering, as would be an algebraic `Fractional` type [as suggested by Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504923/why-isnt-the-fractional-type-orderable-in-haskell#comment84003754_48504923).

Comment: Coming from Java, I see the similarities Haskell's typeclasses and types share with Java's interfaces and concrete types. No issues there, just chose the wrong wording. That said, I appreciate the Complex number counterexample — didn't think about that before.

Comment: Would it be possible to see an executable example, or documentation, of what @WillemVanOnsem had suggested? I can't find anything on the topic of algebraic `Fractional` types.